# Foreach loop not showing results in view

Tags: laravel, view

I'm trying to list answers from my database. But I only get blank page even though when I run dd it shows the collection. Here's the relevant code:

Controller file:

```
public function index($subject_id, Request $request)
    {
        $answers=AnalizaAnswer::where('subject_id', $subject_id)->get();
        return view('analiza.index', compact('answers'));
    }
```

View:

```
<ul>
        @foreach ($answers as $answer)
        <li>{{$answer->answer}}</li>
        @endforeach
</ul>
```

I get a blank page but dd($answers) returns this:

```
Collection {#357 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => AnalizaAnswer {#358 ▼
      #guarded: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "analiza_answers"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▼
        "created_at" => "2019-09-07 16:38:45"
        "updated_at" => "2019-09-07 16:38:45"
        "analiza_question_id" => 1
        "subject_id" => 3
        "user_id" => 56
        "answer" => "Ne"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
    1 => AnalizaAnswer {#359 ▶}
    2 => AnalizaAnswer {#360 ▶}
    3 => AnalizaAnswer {#361 ▶}
    4 => AnalizaAnswer {#362 ▶}
    5 => AnalizaAnswer {#363 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I tried $answer['answer'] but same result. I should mention that I have a triple composite primary key for this table so might be that.

Comment: Are you doing that dd in the controller or in the blade?

Comment: In my blade file.

Comment: Are you able to `dd($answer);` inside your loop?

Comment: Yes, but I only get the first element.

Comment: Can you access any of the other variables on $answer, i.e. can you `dd($answer->user_id);`? and can you confirm that if you dump $answer->answer nothing comes up?

Comment: I can access user_id but again only get one list element. And dd($answer->answer) only returns one list element too.

Comment: Yeah it would only return one because your killing the process (dump and *die*) - so question is, if the data is there, why isn't it printing out in your forloop? Can you try doing `<p>$answers->first()->answer</p>` **outside of your loop**, this should hopefully print out the first answer's answer

Comment: Does every answer have an 'answer'? Or is it a nullable field

Comment: <p>$answers->first()->answer</p> still nothing. And yes, every answer has an 'answer'.

Comment: Sorry should have added the curly brackets `<p>{{ $answers->first()->answer }}</p>`. Let me know what the solution I've given produces then we can work from there :)